# Can I open an app closed in Objective-c with Core Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm developing an app with Core Bluetooth in objective-c. And I have a question. If the user close the app or presh home button and this go to background, could my app turn open when my device send a signal by bluetooth?

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you read and try this? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1

Comment: Sorry, but I have read only about Background Execution in this article.And I want know about closed apps. I don't know if background is similar to closed or no.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can show a notification to the user and the user can then *decide* to open your application. You can't force the app to be opened automatically, without user's consent.

That's actually the whole point of notifications - bring the user's attention to something that is happening in your app.